# Error loading FMU with Python Library pyfmi

Tags: python, pyfmi

I am using Mac M1 Chip. I want to load FMU file generated with Dymola using the python library pyfmi. I have got the following error:

> The FMU could not be loaded. Error loading the binary.

[image]

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that FMUs are basically containers for executable code, so it must have been created with binaries of the right type. It seems to me that the message is pretty clear: *the FMU contain no binary for this platform.* I suggest you start by verifying that the tool generating the FMU can generate the right binaries.

Btw, there are source code FMUs too. In that case the FMU source code must be compiled on the platform before it can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking into the FMU zip "binaries" folder to check if the platform-specific binaries are generated or not.

Additionally, Dymola doesn't support MAC OS. You must cross-compile a source code FMU using FMPy for instance github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy (which is available for MacOS).